# Access to XMLHttpRequest at x from origin y has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express, cors, vercel

I know there are a few similar questions but they didn't fit my scenerio.
They were talking about cors issue in localhost but in my case that works.

I've deployed a rest api and a react frontend to vercel. I put cors config in both my `index.js` and `vercel.json` file and it did work then but now its not working. I just added a redis instance in one file I dont think that should effect it.

My entire error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://scribe-backend.vercel.app/api/notes' from origin 'https://scribe-note-taker.vercel.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

Here's my index.js:

```
const corsOptions = {
  origin: ["https://scribe-note-taker.vercel.app", "http://localhost:5000"],
  methods: "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS",
  credentials: true,
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
};

app.options("*", cors());
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use("/api", userRouter, notesRouter);
```

vercel.json:

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "./index.js",
      "use": "@vercel/node"
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "/",
      "methods": ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH", "OPTIONS"],
      "headers": {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I've no idea why I'm still getting this. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.